# How do I write Python code that enters a file and outputs its 'type-size' properties?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, visual-studio-code, tkinter

How do I write Python code that enters a file'pdf,word, png...' and outputs its 'type-size' properties ?

How do I write Python code that enters a file and outputs its 'type-size' properties

Comment: Specifically what file attributes are you after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the type check this out:

https://pypi.org/project/filetype/

For the size you can just use os.path.getsize()